# XAML Desiger not showing up, just black code to the right

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem, I'm new to visual studio and C#. I want to make WPF application but when l create XAML file I cant see designer, it's only some black text in the right but with first XAML file that I get from making new WPF project it works, every new that I make it doesn't and when I open some project that has XAML files same thing happens.[ss of my vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soq6d.jpg)

I haven't found anyone having the same problem.

Comment: App.XAML doesn’t have a designer. Open a Window or UserControl XAML file to see the designer.

Comment: None of them have designer, when l make new WPF project it work, when l close it and open it again this happens. In my screenshot l was in App.XAML but Window.XAML is same. When l right click and press show designer nothing happens.

Comment: Look at your Solution Explorer: You don’t have a project loaded. You’re in Folder-mode. That’s why.

Answer (score 0):

As Dai said, you are now in folder mode.
[image]
You can try the following steps：

[image]

[image]

Hope it can help you！